# Using Own map on OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-3

Is it possible to use your own map on OpenLayers3? And if so where can I find the information, if you are able to provide me that I be very thankfull ;)

Greetings,
Tristan

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Please, clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to run your own mapserver then take a look at http://geoserver.org. You'll have plenty of example on their web site.